# Ubuntu 17.10 launcher gutter

Tags: ubuntu-dock

I just installed Ubuntu 17.10 and found my launcher (the dock against the left edge) is now very hard to use.

The reason is: the top edge of the screen is now an "Activities Bar", and the bottom (left) corner is now 9 dots for "Show Applications".

Both these things are interfering with my ability to scroll my Launcher up and down by reducing the pointer zone to initiate scrolling. Ideally the Launcher should be full height.

Any suggestions?

[Video of problem](https://youtu.be/gHwiQ7hCF_A)

Answer (score 1):

You can use that bar as any other dock, forcing not expanding the bar:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/extend-height false
```

then change the position to “down” using the dock settings in Ubuntu. You can use your apps from the 9 dot menu in the dock and the activities button in more natural way…

Side bar as normal dock:

[image: Side bar as normal dock]